# How many 4 digits number can be formed with 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1

Tags: combinatorics

I can not find a way to solve this question without writing all the possible numbers.
Notice that we only have a limited quantity of each number. For example, we can only use 1 twice.
Also, please note that the ones, two's and three's are non-distinct.
Thank you for sparing the time to read my question.

Comment: Have you gone over combinations and permutations?

Comment: Listing and counting is a viable strategy, but unpleasant.  Or else divide into cases: (i) one pair and two singletons; (ii) two pairs; (iii) one triple and a singleton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can have no $1$, one $1$, or two $1$s. With no $1$ we have $2^4$ choices, but $2222$ and $3333$ are forbidden. One $1$ we can place in ${4\choose1}$ ways, and then we can fill the other three places at will. Two $1$s we can place in ${4\choose2}$ ways, and then we can fill the other two places at will. It follows that in all there are
$$(2^4-2)+{4\choose1}\cdot 2^3+{4\choose2}\cdot 2^2=70$$
possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. This is the best method, and if I am understanding it correctly, it can be used to analyze more complex scenarios

Answer (score 3):

There are three cases to consider:  the four-digit number either uses one number three times, two numbers twice, or one number twice and two numbers once each.

In the first case, there are $2$ choices (a $2$ or a $3$ but not a $1$) for the number that gets used three times and $2$ choices for the remaining number, which can appear as any of the $4$ digits, for a total of

$$2\times2\times4=16$$

possibilities.

In the second case, there are ${3\choose2}=3$ ways to pick the two numbers that get used twice, and ${4\choose2}=6$ ways to arrange them as a $4$-digit number for a total of

$$3\times6=18$$

possibilites.

In the third case there are $3$ ways to choose the number that appears twice, ${4\choose2}=6$ ways to assign as two of the four digits, and $2$ ways to insert the other two numbers as digits, for a total of

$$3\times6\times2=36$$

possibilities.

In all, we have

$$16+18+36=70$$

different $4$-digit numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. This method is very useful when the number of cases is not very large

Answer (score 1):

All the numbers are, in some sense, of the form aaaa, aaab,aabb, aabc. The first one can't be, cause there are not more than 3 of each digit.

The second one: choose the a: $\binom{2}{1}$. choose the places for it $\binom{4}{3}$. Choose b: $\binom{2}{1}$. There are $\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{2}{1}=16$

For the third one, choosing a and b give us $\binom{3}{2}$. Choosing the places for a, automatically are choosing places for b:$\binom{4}{2}$. Thus, there are $\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2}=3\times 6=18$ numbers with only two digits.

Por the fourth one, choose the repeated digit: $\binom{3}{1}$. Choose the places for it: $\binom{4}{2}$. The other two digits can be arranged in two ways. Then, there are $2\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}=36$.

Therefore, answer is $16+18+36=70$

Comment: What about $aaab$?

Comment: Thank you, this is also a very useful solution.